# Branch.io - how to create custom links

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, deep-linking

Im creating an application where you can make an challenge with the parameters: category, title, days, frequency, bet.

If you set all the parameters you can **invite friends** to do the challenge with you. So my question is what is the best way to invite friends through whatsapp/email/facebook.

My first thought was **deeplinking**.

*So I dived into Branch.io - you can create a deeplink on the website, this works. But I need to set **my own parameters into the link** because the user can specify many parameters.*

Whats the best way to do this?

*Edit*

[Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQbzD.jpg)

Comment: Can you please share a diagram or something to be more clear? It is not that clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **can** create links **dynamically** with Branch.io (as opposed to static on their website).

If you check out this section of their docs : https://docs.branch.io/pages/links/integrate/ spesifically **Create deep links**, you can see that you have a few ways of creating links (dynamically) to which you can append **any key-value** pairs that you wish.
Using the key-value pairs, you can pass any data that you want.
(I guess that in your app the key-value pairs will hold the properties the user selected for the challenge )

You have a pretty good explanation of how to do it here : https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/ios/#create-deep-link

Comment: Thanks! This is what I needed